# Adding gridlines between points on ggmap

Tags: r, ggmap

*edit: image was not visible in first post

I am new to ggmap. I am trying to plot specific points from grids on to a map, but I only have the gps coordinates for the corners of the grids. Is there a way to build a 10 X 10 grid between these points, extract the center of the squares in those grids, and plot a subset of those points?

here is what my map looks like now, with the four corners of three different grids. I would prefer not to include code, as it contains location data.
[image]

I am not sure how to go about this, or if it is even possible.

Comment: *"here is what my map looks like now"*, did you forget to attach the image? (Don't worry that it does not automatically show, somebody will likely edit to make it visible.) Also, please consider giving us a reproducible question including minimal code attempted. Thanks.

Comment: Given your areas are irregular quadrilaterals, do you want 1) an irregular grid of irregularly sized cells with centroids in uniformi-sh rows and columns, 2) an irregular grid of equal area, resulting in very irregular centroid distribution , or 3) a regular grid overlaid on each area with mostly regular sized cells/centroids but some cells get clipped cells at the perimeter?

Comment: My preference would be uniform rows and columns that leads to irregularly sized cells. I know the grid is made of 11 transects lines, with 11 stations along each transect. Each point of the map represents a corner of that grid. I am trying to locate the gps coordinates at specific transect stations.